# Replace newlines with <br>s within <code> tags in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace all the new lines inside a `<code></code>` tags with `<br>`s, but my regex does not work. Here is the input text:

```
<p>
   <span class="dingus">►</span> for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
</p>
<code class="hl">
    Text in a code pre element
    is displayed in a fixed-width
    font, and it preserves
    both      spaces and
    line breaks
</code>
<p class="ar">
    <a href="/editing-help" target="_edithelp">formatting help »</a><br>
    <a href="/questions/how-to-ask">asking help »</a>
</p>
```

Regex:

```
var txt = str.replace(/<code[^>]*>((.|\n)*?)<\/code>/gm,function(match){
    return match.replace(/\n/gi, '<br>');
});
```

BTW, I know using a parser is the ideal solution, but still would like to know if it's possible with a simple regex for the example above.

Comment: Never ever use regex on HTML tags. I know you know but you know you know so we all know this.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Looks like OP is not parsing HTML with RegExp, they just want to remove new-line characters from a string.

Comment: Ahh I had it in reverse. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want to use regular expressions, try this:

```
var str = 'other\nstuff\noutside<code class="hl">\nText in a pre element\nis displayed in a fixed-width\nfont, and it preserves\nboth      spaces and\nline breaks\n</code>';
var txt = str.replace(/(<code[^>]*>)([\S\s]*?)(<\/code>)/g, function(_, p1, p2, p3){
  return p1 + p2.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + p3;
})
```

It takes the entire contents between `<code>` and `</code>` and replaces `\n` with `<br>` within it.

Answer (score 5):

Better if you don't use regex on HTML tags lie *@sterling-archer* mentioned in comment, take a look at **[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)**, Instead you can do it without regex like :

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].textContent;
list = list.split('\n').join('</br>');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I like the solution but would that replace only the text inside `<code>` even when `str` contains other HTML on it? Basically replace `\n` inside <code> but keep everything in  else `str` the way it is.

Comment: You'e welcome, ithink if you have HTML code inside the tag code change textContent to innerHTML and it'll reserve the HTML tags.